# How many external HD (not 4K or 5K) displays can I use with the 2016 13" MacBook Pro with Touchbar?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, touch-bar, 4k

How many external HD (not 4K or 5K) external displays can I use with the 2016 13" MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, using multiple HDMI to Type-C adapters?

The Touch Bar models also have 4 Type-C ports and an Intel Iris Graphics 550, not an Intel Iris Graphics 540 like the base model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially it will support one display at 5120 x 2880 pixels at 60 Hz or up to two displays at 4096 x 2304 pixels at 60 Hz. Of course, this is the 5K and 4K you're probably already aware of.

However, unofficially you could use more than two external displays via various adaptors, at or below the above resolutions. How many you can use will depend on the specs of the actual displays used. Also, you need to be aware that your MBP fans may start spinning at much faster speeds depending on your setup.

You may find the following [info](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-manually-switch-graphics.html#extdisplays) of interest to you. While not directly about the 2016 MBP, the info is still relevant.

Comment: So, in short, is the answer is two?

Comment: Officially yes, two. Unofficially more. Whether you would use more depends on how hard you sense your computer working (e.g. Fans) with the specific displays you're connected to and the resolutions you're using. And it may depend on what software you use as well. If using more external displays is a priority, you really should opt for the 15" model. Apple officially Supports two displays at 5120 x 2880 pixels at 60 Hz or up to four displays at 4096 x 2304 pixels at 60 Hz on these models. This is because the 15" model gives you the option of various AMD Radeon Pro graphics cards as a 2nd GPU.